# vagrant plugin gives gem install error

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

**Background**

The command `vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater` gives the following error

> Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
>   reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
>   caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
>   issues. The error from Bundler is:
>
> An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.14), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.14'` succeeds before
>   bundling.
>
> Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using
>   `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may
>   result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a
>   block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To
>   upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config
>   disable_multisource true`.Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build
>   gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /home/me/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c /usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r
> ```
>
> ./siteconf20161115-3798-7g7yrs.rb extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header
>   files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/me/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.14 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /home/me/.vagrant.d/gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.14/gem_make.out

**The error/problem**

So I ran `sudo gem install ffi -v '1.9.14'` (without sudo I get a permission error)

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing ffi:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c /usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161115-4273-wovmbb.rb extconf.rb
>   mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
>   /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.14/gem_make.out

I tried un-installing vagrant and ruby it doesn't help.
Does anybody know what is going wrong here?

Comment: How did you install Ruby? If from yum or rpm, did you include the devel package? In general we recommend using rbenv or RVM as they allow you to manage your Ruby installation without worrying about using `sudo` or having admin privileges.

Comment: @theTinMan With sudo apt-get istall vagrant Can you link to a example?